# Debian Squeeze wifi interrupted no way to re-enable

Tags: wifi

So I am messing around with Linux on my desktop.  I really like it as an OS and it runs flawlessly on my laptop. Desktop as long as its kernel 2.6 and lower it runs just as good.

My issue being that my NIC being an Alfa awus036h will connect to the internet but it won't let me surf the web. I get two pages in and it pops up the "You have been disconnected" message. I go to right click on the networking icon in the tint2 Bar and I'm presented with no option to re-enable wireless.

lsusb does recognizes the driver even after it shuts down. The unit itself still flickers on / off as if it still running and getting a signal.

Any ideas what is going on here and how to fix it?